# Apple Developer Page says my iOS develpment type certificate will be expired soon

Tags: ios, certificate

1. I already distibuted iOS In-House App. And Apple Developer Page says iOS Development Type Certificate will be expired.
2. My Question is "Do I have to rebuild and redistribute with renewed iOS Development Type Certificate (not Distribution Type Certificate) ?"
3. Or is it fine that I just renew iOS Development Type Certificate and 
   do nothing ?

[image]

Comment: Renew your certificates on Developer Account and configure it on your mac for further application development and distribution process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renew your iOS Development Certificate, download and open it and use it for your next distribution.
Also check your iOS Distribution Certificate for expiration.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're meaning.. if I only renew iOS Development Type Certification and don't rebuild my app right now, that has no problems even if I redistribute app after it's expiration because it is just for Development and Device Test not for Distribution, right?

Comment: Yes, the iOS Development Certificate is only used when you are developing your app.